# Change parts of a string

Tags: java

I'm basically doing the "Replace" funktion from the Notepad but I don't manage to delete/replace parts of a String I read from a .txt file.

I have: "1=55.748555 -0.000000 1.210479 0.000000 0"

I want: "1=55.748555 -1 1.210479"

While I want to manually give it the -1

Since I cause some sort of confusion here my code down below. I haven't started on the replace part, because I don't know how.

```
package txtzuibl;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
public class Txt_zu_ibl {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    String zeile = "";
    int i =0;
    zeile ="Closed Index Arclength";
    bw.write(zeile);
    bw.newLine();
    zeile="Begin section ! 1";
    bw.write(zeile);
    bw.newLine();
    zeile=" Begin curve ! 1";
    bw.write(zeile);
    bw.newLine();
    while( zeile != null )
    //Some editing on the beginning
    {
      i++;
      System.out.print(i+" ");
      //Just for me so I can check if I didn't screw up 
      System.out.println(zeile);
      zeile = br.readLine();
      if( i>57 )
      {
          bw.write(zeile);
          bw.newLine();
      }

    }
    bw.close();
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: We won't do your homework. Show us your code, and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: That's no homework. Thats extrawork for me trying to be lazy in the future;-). But shure. I will edit.

Comment: Which part exactly are you stuck on? Reading the file? Reading the manual part? Doing the string replacement?

Comment: Only the replacement. The rest I've sort of managed.

Comment: where is the code for replace

Comment: @psaraj12 that's exactly my problem. I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Is there some sort of *rule* that defines what should be replaced by what? I can see that "-0.000000" should become "-1", and that "0.000000" should disappear, as well as a single "0". Is that all?

Comment: @ laune There is one but that is to complicated and has to do with where I measure. So if I have a manual imput it will be much easier. But you are right. Only "-0.000000" replace with "-1" and "0.000000 0 " should disappear.

Comment: So my answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace parts of a string, replace or replaceAll can be used. First try:

```
String s = "1=55.748555 -0.000000 1.210479 0.000000 0";
s = s.replace( "-0.000000", "-1" );
s = s.replace( "0.000000", "" );
s = s.replace( "0", "" );  // Oh no! this doesn't work because...
```

This is not OK, because it'll also kill the zero in 1.210479. So let's use regular expressions:

```
s = s.replaceAll( "-0.000000\\b", "-1" );  // exactly six decimal places
s = s.replaceAll( "\\b0.000000\\b", "" );
s = s.replaceAll( "\\b0\\b", "" );
```

The last two can be combined

```
s = s.replaceAll( "\\b0(?:.000000)?\\b", "" );
```

Or, if the zeros after the decimal point can be any positive number:

```
s = s.replaceAll( "\\b0(?:.0+)?\\b", "" );
```

Some spaces (from between the removed numbers) will remain. You can clean these up by another replaceAll that collapses excess spaces:

```
s = s.replaceAll( "\\s{2,}", " " );
```

Comment: Thanks a buch! I love you!